# Can I use multiple languages for the language detection API in python?

Tags: python, google-translator-toolkit

I'm trying to build my own automatic voice to text translator here is my code so far...

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from googletrans import Translator
from textblob import TextBlob

translator = Translator()
speech = sr.Recognizer()


with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("say something!")
    audio = speech.listen(source)
    ToTranslate = speech.recognize_google(audio, language='ko')
    Translate = ToTranslate                            ####^^####
    print(Translate)
    try:
        print("The language used is: " )
        print("You said: " + ToTranslate)
        translation = translator.translate(ToTranslate).text
        print("In english: " + translation)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sorry I can't understand you.")
    except sr.RequestError:
        print("Error")
```

If I want for it to automatically detect the language, what should I do?